# Retrieving declaration not supported for filetype

Tags: vimrc, bash, lsp, filetype-bash

I am currently using `vim-lsp` for bash.

As in https://github.com/bash-lsp/bash-language-server#vim I have added in my `~/.vimrc` the followings :

```
if executable('bash-language-server')
  au User lsp_setup call lsp#register_server({
        \ 'name': 'bash-language-server',
        \ 'cmd': {server_info->[&shell, &shellcmdflag, 'bash-language-server start']},
        \ 'allowlist': ['sh'],
        \ })
endif
```

However, when I use the command as `:LspDefinition`, I got the error `Retrieving definition not supported for filetype 'sh'` . Any idea how to fix this ?